# Is Symfony3 as maintainable and powerful as Symfony2 regarding of functionality and comunity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm starting a project using Synfony and wondering which version I should use to develop it.

I knows that Symfony2 is used by a lot of people and there is a lot of Bundles already made in order to make the programation easier and faster.
Documentation is also well made with this version. 
But the 3.0 is available and I should probably use the latest version if I want my code stable and maintained longer.

- Is it possible to use bunbles from 2.x version in Synfony 3 ?
- What are the main diferencies betwin those two versions ?
- Any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at [UPGRADE-3.0.md](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md) should be sufficient to answer your first two questions. For the advices, look at the symfony [installation page](http://symfony.com/download) and the [3.0 roadmap](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-3-0-the-roadmap). For new features over stability, go to 3.x. For stability over new features, go on 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*- Is it possible to use bunbles from 2.x version in Synfony 3 ?*

Yes, you can easily use a bundle from sf2 to sf3, but in deal with functionality of this bundle perhaps migration don't run correctly without upgrade of this bundle. The modification in bundle for run correctly in sf3 is not very important. But yes the migration is easy but not automatic. Warning at this point and read about which bundle for knowing is this bundle work with technical layer of sf3 and if little change code done for running into sf3.

*- What are the main differencies between those two versions ?*

You can read this documentation dealing with this point : [migrate SF version](http://symfony.com/blog/transition-from-symfony-2-7-to-3-0-symfony-2-8-on-its-way) and this : [recipes about upgrading](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/upgrade/index.html)

**WARNING :** speak about sf2 only is not efficient because exist a gap between sf2.7 and sf2.8 because sf2.7 is not ready to migrate sf3 but sf2.8 is prepared for migrate sf3 because lot of deprecated are erased for more easily migrate.

The question of your issue depends of this point of your version of Symfony2

If you have an application with symfony2 version less than 2.8, you migration will be expensive and not easily (but possible).
If you have an application with symfony2 version greater than 2.7, you can easily migrate to symfony3 (find information of which bundle that use before migrate)

*- Any advice ?*

Lot of documentation exist for this but just few points :

- if gap is to higher for symfony3, not migrate but rewrite application
- if gap is little, construct list of bundle third-party and your specific controller and analyse change with this.