# do Symfony 2 bundles work with Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to Symfony and I'm looking at integrating a few bundles into my application, but all the bundles I find are for Symfony 2. How different are 2/3 and what sort of issues might I find myself in when I integrate them?

for example, i am looking at using this one: http://knpbundles.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle

but it's only valid for Symfony 2 and I won't want to spend an age trying to integrate it and coming across incompatibility issues.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to provide an answer although the question is very poor because it's much too broad.

Of course there is no general rule which Symfony based bundle will work in which Symfony version unless it's clearly stated in the available official documentation of the bundle.

A couple of indications:

1. **Check the CHANGELOG, README etc files of your bundles**. E.g. in the CHANGELOG of SonataAdminBundle you will find a lot of changes and bug fixes regarding Symfony > 3.0 - so this is a strong indication that Symfony > 3.0 is supported.
2. **Check the composer.json of the bundle**, if there's any. It might be the case that Symfony is required and you can find a semver version. E.g. for the Sonata Admin bundle there a lots of Symfony components required in composer.json. All of them state something like: `"symfony/class-loader": "^2.3 || ^3.0"` which means that it requires at least Symfony 2.3 or 3.0 - again a strong indication it'll work with Symfony > 3.0.

But in the end: dependency management is an all-timer issue and you'll have to check.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the downvote - can somebody please explain why I got this? I will vote to close the question now.

Answer (score 0):

Most of Symfony 2.8+ bundles work out of the box with Symfony 3. Symfony 3 is not so different from the previous version.

You can easily check if a Bundle is not compatible with Symfony3 enabling it on version 2 and then looking for deprecations using the profiler.

> [...] you can easily use a bundle from sf2 to sf3, but in deal with functionality of this bundle perhaps migration don't run correctly without upgrade of this bundle. The modification in bundle for run correctly in sf3 is not very important. But yes the migration is easy but not automatic. Warning at this point and read about which bundle for knowing is this bundle work with technical layer of sf3 and if little change code done for running into sf3.

The previous quote is taken from [this SO answer about the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36402657/1977778)